# SQLite android with SUGAR ORM to add save contacts

Tags: android, android-studio, listview

Creating an app using SQLlite, in which user can add, edit, update and delete the groups and contacts created.. User can add multiple groups and unlimited groups can be added within the groups also unlimited contacts can be added within the groups. I want to count the number of contacts added within the group example. I have created three groups a,b and c and I have added 3 groups and 2 contacts in the group a so it should count 2 contacts in the group a because I have added 2 contacts in it.. I am attaching the code for your review, please help me to fix it as I am not able to count the contacts added in the groups

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1dL-j-vuqfoCEI_na399q_ggLkgyZnC5U